# Authorize User Before Hitting Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, controller

I want to authorize users before executing controller actions. In each of the actions, There are duplicated lines of code.

Is there a method so that I will able to authorize users in `ControllerBase`?

For example, I want to have a `CustomControllerBase` to put authorization logic there:

```
public class CustomBaseController : ControllerBase {
   // authorization logic
}
```

Then controllers inherit from `CustomBaseController`

```
public class FooController : CustomBaseController {
}
```

Here is how I authorize a user:

```
var userItem = dbService.GetAuthorizedUser(User) // ClaimsPrincipal
if (userItem == null) return Unauthorized(ResponseMessage.UnAuthorized);
```

The first 2 lines of code are run in each action.

Comment: I can only speculate why someone down voted it. I guess it is because ASP.NET (Core) does have [authentication and authorisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) mechanism built in.

Comment: @dropoutcoder, as I said, I want to remove duplicate lines of code

Comment: As I am trying to explain. There is built in mechanism that should be used to do what you wanna do. I have never seen security to be used directly inside the controller classes. You may want to rephrase the question or add more code.

Comment: @dropoutcoder, I put some more details.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but that should be done completely elsewhere. Let me write it down to an answer.

Comment: Look into middleware for net core.  You can do the auth stuff and return a result before it ever hits an action.  Otherwise if all is good, the action will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use ASP.NET (Core) built-in security features.

Authorize only authenticated user, unless specified differently on controller or action with global fallback policy.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Enable authentication and authorization middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Create authorization requirements with desired logic.

```
public class DefaultAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    private IDbService _dbService;

    public DefaultAuthorizationHandler(IDbService dbService)
    {
        _dbService = dbService;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        // We skip as user is not authenticated. Nothing to authorize
        if (context.User == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // 
        var userItem = _dbService.GetAuthorizedUser(context.User);

        if (userItem != null)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        // in some cases you want to have strict requirement
        // to force used to be denied even if other requirements are met.
        // context.Fail();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register authorization handler to DI.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, DefaultAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Make login endpoint to allow anonymous users by overriding fallback policy.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginController
{
    ...
}
```

Related resources:

[ASP.NET Core security topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: You are welcome. Happy you have solved your problem.